# How to stack open windows side by side

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

Windows explorer = Nautilus

Like in Windows OS u can stack explorers side by side vertically and horizontally , can the same be done in Ubuntu 12.04???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Horizontally**:

Just drag a window to the screen edge and it should automatically take up half of the screen. Do the same for the other edge and you should have two equal sized window tiles next to each other.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts, such as Alt-Ctrl-Numpad Left and Alt-Ctrl-Numpad Right also work - http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-ubuntu-unity-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 13):

You can semi-maximize current window to the left or right side of the screen by pressing Ctrl + Super (Windows key) + Left or Right. Press and hold the Super Key to see all available Keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is 8 years old now, an update to the answer by thanos for **Ubuntu 20**:

`Super (Windows key)` + `Left Arrow` or `Right Arrow`

will put a window half-maximized to the left or right half of the screen (Ctrl key not required anymore).

Comment: Alt + F8 to enable resize mode and Esc or the Enter key to get out of the resize mode.
More information: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-split-screen/

Answer (score 0):

For 22.04 LTS. You can check out [Tiling Assistant](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3733/tiling-assistant/)

It's a must have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).