# Is there a way to cascade windows in Unity?

Tags: window

I use `super + W` all the time but I would like to be able to cascade the windows like you're able to do in Windows.

Windows window cascade:
[image: Windows Cascade]
Ubuntu window tile
[image: Unity Tile]

Comment: Not sure what behaviour you are exactly referring to, could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I added pictures to show what I mean. You can do it in [GNOME](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/cascade-windows-gnome-ubuntu) but I couldn't find anything for Unity.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I noticed you did. Thanks. For my understanding: is the cascading a window- arrangement, or just a "pick one and all (other) windows will return to their positions" - feature?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm thinking it's a window-arrangement feature. I've never used it before but I have a lot of windows open at a time and the cascade would make it a lot easier the see them all at once than window tiling.

Comment: Ah, that shouldn't be too difficult (script/shortcut key). I will probably look into it tomorrow or the day after if no one did already.

Answer (score 2):

**Stack windows windows side-by-side**

- If by cascading you meant to say that you want to stack windows windows side-by-side, then, `Super (Windows key)` + `(Right/Left) Arrow`
- Alternatively , you can use `Super (Windows key)` + `up` arrow to maximize, and `down` to un-maximize. This answer was available in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1285872/1141033).

**Using an extension - gnome cascade windows**

- If you are looking for a cascading tool specifically **for gnome shell**, then there is one such extension: [gnome-cascade-windows](https://github.com/Lytol/gnome-cascade-windows)
- After installing, you can use `Super (Windows key)` + `c` to trigger the cascading effect.

**Mouse gestures**

- Alternatively, you can drag the window to one the edges.
- But this operation is very manual. I believe it depends on which side of the window-pane your mouse pointer is at too.